# Is there an algorithm to find the optimal value of k-tsp (traveling salesman) in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, traveling-salesman

I read [this](http://www.springerlink.com/content/k66q7204vr21522t/) article, it suggests (page 1025 last paragraph) that there is a polynomial time algorithm to find the optimum of a k-tsp problem using binary search.
Using binary search would suggest there exists an algorithm for checking if a solution exists with `cost<X` and this algorithm is used for the binary search.
I 'googled' around for this and the only algorithm i could find was a non deterministic one (which is pretty trivial), but obviously i'm looking for a deterministic one.

I am interested in this for learning purposes,

Any help/links would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am referring to finding the value of the optimal solution and not about finding the solution itself.

Comment: Isn't TSP a special case of k-TSP where k = number of nodes in the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since TSP is a special case of k-TSP where k = number of nodes in the graph. If you had a solution for "what's the cheapest k-TSP route" in  polynomial in relation to graph size, then you'd have a polynomial solution to decision problem version of TSP which would imply that P = NP.

So the answer is no. Deterministic polynomial algorithm for both decision problem and optimization version (they're essentially the same) of k-TSP doesn't exist (yet).

Comment: I'm asking about finding what the 'optimal solution' value is, not about finding the actual optimal solution. so your argument does not apply to that.

Comment: @Daniel it's a decision problem version of the TSP. If you had an answer to the question "what's the cheapest TSP route in a graph" you'd have an answer to "if there exists a TSP route that's cheaper than x". Edited the answer to reflect it better.

Comment: that is true. but the opposite is not (unless i'm missing something) if i know what the value of the optimal solution is that does not mean i know the actual solution.

Comment: @Daniel yes. You don't need the actual solution in decision problem version of TSP. You just need the answer if there exists a route cheaper than X (which effectively can answer what the cheapest route value is, using binary search). If you could answer that in P for k-TSP, you'd have it for TSP and if so P would have to be NP.

Comment: thanks, i was not aware the decision version was also NP complete. But this means i don't understand what binary search in the article i referenced means.

Answer (score 0):

The paper you mentioned proposes a polynomial-time **approximation** algorithm for the directed k-TSP problem.

Approximation algorithms are those which are guaranteed to yield solutions with a limited deviation from the optimal solution value. There are examples of polynomial-time approximation algorithms for NP-Hard problems: the [Christofides Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm) yields, in time O(n³), solutions to the metric TSP problem whose values are at most 3/2 the value of the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

David Karger, in a lecture ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaEZyfGTHEs&t=356s))

mentions a randomized algorithm for efficient k-TSP problem which runs in polynomial time in n (but exponential in k). It is based on the idea of color coding: color each of the node with a random color in [1..k], and find a shortest chromatic path (where each color appears exactly once). With a simple dynamic programming algorithm, this approach gives a runtime of O(n^2 2^k) and it succeeds (in finding the path with minimal cost) with probability e^{-k}. By repeating e^k times, one achieves an algorithm that finds the minimum k-TSP with high probability.